# why doesn't my site store the user input data in my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, mysqli

Hi I am a programming beginner and i am trying to make a simple register function on my webbsite , a simple form for the user to fill in and then it should store the data in my database , the problem is that everything works (I Think)  :) but the data / the user information does not store.

```
   <?php
include ("./inc/header.inc.php") $reg = @$_POST['reg'];

$fn = ""; //first name
$ln = ""; //Last name
$un = ""; //User name
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
$d = ""; //sign up date

// registrering av nya användare
// ucheck kontrollerar om användaren redan finns

$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['first_name']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['last_name']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['Username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['Email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['Email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['Password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['Password2']);
$d = date("Y-n-d");

if ($reg)
    {
    if ($em == $em2)
        {
        $u_check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username='$un'");
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
        if ($check == 0)
            {
            if ($fn && $ln && $un && $em && $em2 && $pswd && $pswd2)
                {
                if ($pswd == $pswd2)
                    {
                    if (strlen($un) > 25 || strlen($fn) > 25 || strlen($ln) > 25)
                        {
                        echo "The maximum limit for Username/last name and first name is 25 characters :(";
                        }
                      else
                        {
                        if (strlen($pswd) > 30 || strlen($pswd) < 5)
                            {
                            echo " Your password must be more than 5 characters or less then 30 characters :(";
                            }
                          else
                            {

                            // kryptering av password 1 och 2 med hjälp av md5 innan det sätts i databasen

                            $pswd = md5($pswd);
                            $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (``,`$un`,`$fn`,`$ln`,`$em`,`$pswd`,`$d`,`0`)");
                            die("<h2>You are now a member of the village</h2> Login to get started...");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    echo "Your passwords don´t match :(";
                    }
                }
              else
                {
                echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
                }
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Username already taken ...";
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Your emails dont match :( ";
        }
    }

?>
                    <div style="width: 1000px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Join Today!<h2>
                                </td>
                                <td width="40%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Enter Your information and sign up today!<h2>
                                <form action="#" method= "POST">
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" Size:"30" placeholder="Firstname"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" Size:"30" placeholder="Lastname"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Username" Size:"30" placeholder="Username"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Password" Size:"30" placeholder="Password"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Password2" Size:"30" placeholder="Password Confirmation"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" Size:"30" placeholder="Email"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Email2" Size:"30" placeholder="Email Confirmation"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="Submit" name="reg" Size:"30" placeholder="Sign-up!">
                                    </form>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>


    <?php include ( "./inc/footer.inc.php" )?>
```

Comment: Remove the ticks around the values and use quotes.

Comment: Plus, you're suppressing errors using `@`, and that's where it's "at" ;) and that's a fact Jack. Not putting in an answer and for so many reasons.

Comment: tip - http://phpbeautifier.com/beautify.php

Comment: Since you're not checking for errors, use [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! If you're a beginner then you have the great chance not to learn to use those deprecated mysql_* functions anymore. Better begin right from the start with PDO or MySQLi. Use prepared statements with placeholders right from the start, bind your input values to those placeholders. You won't regret it!

Comment: It should *theoretically* be quotes, but better yet, [**use prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Plus, don't use MD5 for password storage, it's old (*circa 1992*) and is considered broken. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: ok thanks guys what do you mean by that i am supressing errors using @ ? 
should i just remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

you must check your mysqli database connection.
The @ is error suppression operator in PHP.

PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

See:

Error Control Operators
Bad uses of the @ operator
Update:

In your example, it is used before the variable name to avoid the E_NOTICE error there. If in $_POST array, hn key is not set, it will throwE_NOTICE message but @ is used there to avoid that E_NOTICE.

Note that you can also put this line on top of your script to avoid E_NOTICE error:

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
PHP6 Note:

Because @ operator is very slow, it won't work on ini_set eg @ini_set.

You should avoid using it where you can.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include ("./inc/header.inc.php"); 
$reg = $_POST['reg'];

$fn = ""; //first name
$ln = ""; //Last name
$un = ""; //User name
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
$d = ""; //sign up date

// registrering av nya användare
// ucheck kontrollerar om användaren redan finns

$fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$ln = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
$un = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$em = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
$em2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email2']);
$pswd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$pswd2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password2']);
$d = date("Y-n-d");

if ($reg)
{
    if ($em == $em2)
        {
            $u_check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username='$un'");
            $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
            if ($check == 0)
            {
                     if ($fn && $ln && $un && $em && $em2 && $pswd && $pswd2)
                    {
                        if ($pswd == $pswd2)
                            {
                                    if (strlen($un) > 25 || strlen($fn) > 25 || strlen($ln) > 25)
                                        {
                                        echo "The maximum limit for Username/last name and first name is 25 characters :(";
                                        }
                                      else
                                        {
                                                if (strlen($pswd) > 30 || strlen($pswd) < 5)
                                                {
                                                echo " Your password must be more than 5 characters or less then 30 characters :(";
                                                }
                                              else
                                                {
                                                // kryptering av password 1 och 2 med hjälp av md5 innan det sätts i databasen

                                                $pswd = md5($pswd);
                                                $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                                                $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (``,`$un`,`$fn`,`$ln`,`$em`,`$pswd`,`$d`,`0`)");
                                                die("<h2>You are now a member of the village</h2> Login to get started...");
                                                }
                                        }
                            }
                          else
                            {
                            echo "Your passwords don´t match :(";
                            }
                    }
                      else
                        {
                        echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
                        }
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Username already taken ...";
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Your emails dont match :( ";
        }
}

?>
                    <div style="width: 1000px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Join Today!<h2>
                                </td>
                                <td width="40%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Enter Your information and sign up today!<h2>
                                <form  method= "POST">
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" Size:"30" placeholder="Firstname"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" Size:"30" placeholder="Lastname"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Username" Size:"30" placeholder="Username"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Password" Size:"30" placeholder="Password"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Password2" Size:"30" placeholder="Password Confirmation"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" Size:"30" placeholder="Email"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="Email2" Size:"30" placeholder="Email Confirmation"/><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="Submit" name="reg" Size:"30" placeholder="Sign-up!">
                                    </form>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>


    <?php include ( "./inc/footer.inc.php" )?>
```

Comment: ok thanks , i get the @ part now , i tried to run your code with the new strings and it told me that i should use mysqli instead and so on , now i have it all working , just started using the old strip_tags again but i still have the problem that my code does not store the data in my db :/ is that because of the strip tags or am i doing something else wrong?

Comment: First: Use the escaping method only as soon as you need it. I.e. if you insert something into a database, only escape it for the database, i.e. apply mysql_real_escape_string (or PDO->quote or whatever database layer you are using). But don't yet apply any escaping for the output. No strip_tags or similar yet. This is because you may want to use the data stored in the database someplace else, where HTML escaping isn't necessary, but only makes the text ugly.